# Use the database as my context bindinds and not the file system

Tags: java, jboss, jndi

At the moment my jboss-service.xml file points to a context-bindings.xml file on my harddrive.
We have a db structure that holds context bindings and ref addresses in the database.
How do I tell Jboss to point to the database and not the context-bindings.xml file on my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.
Answer was to set the DataSource attribute instead of the FileName attribute

So instead of,

```
<attribute name="FileName">C:\context-bindings.xml</attribute>
```

rather use,

```
<attribute name="DataSource">java:txLifeDS</attribute>
```